# JsonSerializationException, Erro ao converter JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Estou tentando deserializar um objeto trazido pela minha webApi, testei com outros objetos e funciona, mas com esse não
O erro é o seguinte:

> JsonSerializationException: Unexpected JSON token when reading
>   DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1,
>   position 1.

```
/* Método responsável por realizar a impressão */

    public static DataTable TabelaRateios { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Rateio/Report/{Rateio_Codigo}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Report(int Rateio_Codigo)
    {
        int? Emp_Codigo = Services.Token.strEmp_codigo;
        var UrlApi = $"api/Rateio/imprimir/{Rateio_Codigo},{Emp_Codigo}";
        Uri BaseAdress = Services.Token.BaseAdress;
        string strToken = Services.Token.strToken;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAdress;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/Json"));
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(UrlApi))
            {

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string resul = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                TabelaRateios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(resul);
            }
        }    
        Rateio Rateios = new Rateio();

        return View(Rateios);
    }
```

Método na WebApi

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("imprimir/{Rateio_Codigo},{Emp_Codigo}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Imprimir(double Rateio_Codigo, int Emp_Codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var Rateios = bdprincipalEntities.Rateio.Select(
                    x => new {
                        Rateio_Codigo = (int)x.Rateio_Codigo,
                        x.Rateio_descricao,
                        x.Emp_Codigo,
                        Rateio_Situacao2 = x.Rateio_Situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO"
                    }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Rateio_Codigo == Rateio_Codigo && x.Emp_Codigo == Emp_Codigo); ;
            result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Rateios));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Json da string result:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> "{\"Rateio_Codigo\":2,\"Rateio_descricao\":\"VR.VENDAS APÓS DESC.-LD
>   EM GRADUAÇÃO\",\"Emp_Codigo\":1,\"Rateio_Situacao2\":\"ATIVO\"}"

Comment: Olá, ao converter o objeto para String, coloque-o dentro de um par de chaves {}, e verifique se resolveu o problema.

Comment: é isso que você está querendo dizer? `resul = "{" + resul + "}";`

Comment: Isso, pois pelo que parece, ao converter a String para o objeto DataTable, ele espera um Array, e não o objeto em si.

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou, ficou da seguinte maneira a variável result `"{{\"Rateio_Codigo\":2,\"Rateio_descricao\":\"VR.VENDAS APÓS DESC.-LD EM GRADUAÇÃO\",\"Emp_Codigo\":1,\"Rateio_Situacao2\":\"ATIVO\"}}"`

Comment: Opa, perdão amigão, eu quis dizer colocar entre colchetes [ ].

Comment: Desculpe a demora, vou tentar

Comment: @GabrielFerreira Funcionou, muito obg, poderia posta uma resposta por favor? E se puder me explicar também, agradeço